# Assigning a string to a JavaScript var from django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have the following template:

```
var url = {{url}};
$.getJSON(url...
```

and the following view:

```
return render_to_response('template.html', {"url":"/this/url/"})
```

but for some reason javascript does not treat this as a `string`. Is there a reason why? What is the syntax that I should be using?

Comment: What does the JavaScript source look like after the template has been parsed?

Comment: '{{url}}' as stated by everyone else. A little piece of advice, it is never a good idea to get in the habit of having dynamically written JS. Better to write all objects to a single JSON object and then reference in inside your Javascript - much easier to maintain as it keeps all your dynamic objects in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in your template:

```
var url = {{url}};
```

Will become this:

```
var url = /this/url;
```

There are no quotes in the template, and there are no quotes in the string, so there are no quotes in the output.  You should use this:

```
var url = "{{url}}";
```

or even better:

```
var url = "{{url|escapejs}}";
```

so that special characters will be treated properly.